# Where does Adobe Flash CS4 store config changes? Eg Actions panel location, size etc?

Tags: adobe-cs4, adobe-flash

So my actions panel in Adobe CS4 authoring interface is somehow expanded taller than any of my monitors.  It isn't a true window so I can use `move` from the task bar.  It won't allow itself to be shoved above the top of the window and the vertical resize and resize all interfaces are only on the bottom.  There is no maximize interface.

Using `move` on the main Flash app does not affect the Actions panel.

Docking and undocking the panel to the panels area has no effect on size.

Restarting Flash or PC has no effect.

Resizing horizontally and moving the panel from monitor to monitor are remembered between restarts of Flash and the PC so it is writing these changes down somewhere.

Places I have looked:

C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Application Data

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4

Any help locating the config file or resizing the Actions panel most appreciated.

TIA

JG

Comment: My guess would be that on Windows it would be in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my action panel. I do where to adjust the height manually but here's how you can solve it using two monitors:
- make sure 'mirroring' between monitors is turned off.
- arrange your monitors so they are not left and right of each other, but rather top-and-bottom.
-when you drag the action panel to the upper monitor, the bottom edge of the panel should be draggable at your lower monitor.

Comment: Thanks!  Where are you from?  My brother's name is Laurens.  We are from South Carolina and Laurens is an old family name with us.